# An Array inside object is not removed properly

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array called locations

```
const [location,setLocation]=useState([]);


const addLocation=(place)=>{  // place={name:"abc",pin:"232",person:[]} 
    const _location=[...location];
    const person1={name:"dfg",age:"10"}
    place.person.push(person1);
    setlocation([...location,place]);
}

const removeLocation=(index)=>{
    const _location=[...location];
    _location.splice(index,1) 
setLocation(_location);
}
```

the state become empty

But issue is if i add the same person again the person array is increased with same object again
like this

```
{name:"abc",pin:"232",person:[{name:"dfg",age:"10"},{name:"dfg",age:"10"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

Before you add the person to the location you've to check whatever he might already exists.
You could do this easily like that:

```js
const addLocation = (place) => {
    const _location=[...location];
    const person1={name:"dfg",age:"10"};
    if(place.person.findIndex(e => e.name === person1.name) === -1)
        place.person.push(person1);
    setlocation([...location,place]);
}
```

In my example I only check for the persons name. You could add other stuff as well ofc.

Comment: yes I could do but i'm removing the object entirely from location array ,and after i'm adding in to it .Why this happening ,Is it referring any temp data 
any solution for that without checking isexitsing

Comment: Well the lambda for the `removeLocation` will capture the current location array (at least in your current code). So when you're changing the array you'll not actually change the array that `removeLocation` is working with.

Comment: any solution for that

Comment: Do the `const [location,setLocation]=useState([]);` within your removeLocation and addLocation method ;)

Comment: Thanks any I found the https://github.com/kolodny/immutability-helper this library could solve this mutation issues Thanks any way